# Strange RichTextBox behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

Imagine you have a RichTextBox, with the following lines and caret position (|):

```
one
tw|o
```

If you hold Shift, press the Up arrow key, and then press End, in RichTextBox, you now have the following selection:

```
one
[tw]o
```

This is odd.  Most text boxes will selection from the end of the previous line, not the beginning of the current line.  Here's the selection you'd get in most text boxes:

```
one[
tw]o
```

Does anyone know how I could avoid this strange RichTextBox behaviour?  I've tried handling the case where Shift and End are held in OnKeyDown, and then setting SelectionStart, but it won't work.

**Edit:**

This question has apparently caused some confusion, so here are some screenshots.

Desired behaviour:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkQ9W.png

Actual behaviour:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oon4Z.png

Comment: RTB is commonly mistaken for a text editor.  It is not.  It can only colorize real text, not virtual space.

Comment: I'm using TextBox right now, but it's very limited.  Single undo, no Ctrl+Backspace, etc.  I'm writing an open-source text editor.  Can you suggest something better?  On a side note, I don't why you mentioned colorising.  I have no need for that.

Comment: @Tom: Ok I see your point here. the problem then that the cursor will be at the beginning of the second line instead of being at the end of the first line. I tested it and yes you are right!

Comment: It seems to me like a pure rendering difference.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom: Hans has your answer as to why it does not work. Try something like CkEditor. http://ckeditor.com/ It will give you the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how Hans's response is relevant to my question.  I'm asking why RTB has this behaviour, when almost every other text box doesn't, and how to get around this behaviour.  In any case, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Tom: Maybe I misunderstood Hans response. But, I believe the case is that in the RTB it will only highlight actual text not invisible characters such as /r/n. Your desired behavior actually include the invisible characters at the end of the line. The proof is if you copy and paste this value into a text editor that shows these characters you will see this:

From RTB

tw

From ckeditor

<CR><LF>
tw

So, you can see that the RTB does not actually select the <CR><LF> characters. Why? I haven't a clue! Possibly because the RTB stores each line in a string array and not as free text?